# Will replacing 'extern const' with 'static const' affect performance?

Tags: c, performance, static, global, extern

Our C code base stores all global constants across two files:

```
//global.h
extern const long double ACCELERATION_GRAVITY_FTS;
extern const long double PI;
extern const long double DEG_TO_RAD;
extern const long double RAD_TO_DEG;
extern const long double GC_NM_PER_RAD;
extern const long double FEET_PER_NM;
...
```

---

```
//global.c
const long double ACCELERATION_GRAVITY_FTS = 32.17405;
const long double PI = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795;
const long double DEG_TO_RAD = 0.01745329251994329576923690768489;
const long double RAD_TO_DEG = 57.295779513082320876798154814105;
const long double GC_NM_PER_RAD = 3437.74677471314;
const long double FEET_PER_NM = 6076.1155;
```

To avoid repetition, I would like to refactor these into a single file:

```
//global.h
static const long double ACCELERATION_GRAVITY_FTS = 32.17405;
static const long double PI = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795;
static const long double DEG_TO_RAD = 0.01745329251994329576923690768489;
static const long double RAD_TO_DEG = 57.295779513082320876798154814105;
static const long double GC_NM_PER_RAD = 3437.74677471314;
static const long double FEET_PER_NM = 6076.1155;
//global.c no longer exists
```

Although this is clearly a good refactor in terms of maintainability,
is it practical for performance and executable size?

Comment: the `static const` way gives the opportunity for the compiler to replace variable references with constant expressions.

Comment: In C, this is a very bad idea. These are no constants, but _constant variables_. I.e. they are accessed like variables, and the `const` is only a guarantee by the programmer not to write to them. Problem is they will not be optimized, e.g. as immediate loads. The C-way is to `#define` them as macros, making then true constants.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode So, you're saying static const can be applied at compile time much like C++'s constexpr keyword?  Well that sounds like it could provide even better performance than the extern approach.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode: I would not bet on that in C. This is one of the differences between C and C++.

Comment: @TrevorHickey: To make sure, you should try. C does not guarantee this; a compiler **might**, however, optimize, but only for `static`, not cross-CU.

Comment: @Olaf, Ok.  Regardless of whether this optimization takes place, you're saying the opposite could very well happen.  If static was used, the same variable may end up being stored in the binary more than once(because it exists across each translation unit that included it)?

Comment: @Olaf I said "gives the opportunity". Compilers are smarter than you're giving them credit for. Unless you made the variables also `volatile` I would bet money they get optimized into constants with optimizations on. But you are right in saying that there is no guarantee of this. A macro would give you a solid guarantee.

Comment: @TrevorHickey: I'd definitively stick with the C way. There is nothing wrong using macros for such constants. Although I think a name `PI` is a bit short for a global identifier - be it macro or variable. The only justification using variables is imo here if you need to take their address. If so, a single global variable is the correct way, but that is also very unlikely to be optimized in any way.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode: I've seen pigs fly, but I wouldn't bet a cent. It is not just the compiler, but also the architecture. If you have a single object, your compiler may not have it multiple times, so for some architectures, it _has_ to generate code to read it from the rodata section, while it could store the constants in literal pool or near the program code whereever it is required. Welcome to prove me wrong for the major compilers and architectures and their default and max. optimization levels (max. speed and min code-size, please!).

Comment: @Olaf [gcc (all versions) and clang (all versions) do the optimization I'm talking about](https://goo.gl/6hdi9i). Which I already knew they did, but here's your proof.

Comment: @Olaf [they even optimize memory dereferencing straight to literals](https://goo.gl/SiIc4r)

Comment: @Olaf I think you misunderstand how a compiler manages literals. I'm only talking for a sane compiler now, but it doesn't store numeric literals in the binary apart from where they will be loaded in; so not in the rodata or bss but directly inline in the asm. rodata is more of an array or string literal sort of thing because they require a pointer to an element. I see why you would think it doesn't perform the optimization if the numeric literal were stored in the rodata though. My bad if I misunderstand what you mean there though.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode: I did my fair amount of compiler design myself and know vey well how they optimize. Do **you** know how this is implemented in machine-code for all main archs? This is very different for x86 and the various ARMs, not to speak about the others. `const` data is normally placed in `.rodata`,  not in `.text`. Not to mention caching or the problems with Flash for MCUs.

Comment: @Olaf Yes. I don't tend to fiddle around with machine language because that's more of a JIT compiler or assembler sort of thing, but I do know how it works. I've written an AOT compiler for x86 and x86-64 that used nasm, so I'm pretty familiar there, but not with ARM. I imagine it's all really similar, though. *`const`* data is usually stored in `.rodata`, but *literals* aren't. That would just be weird. A good compiler will translate that header into a bunch of *literals*. Even my cruddy compiler can do that with my cruddy language.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode: There are quite some differences, as ARM can only load immediates of limited range with a single instruction and - as a typical RISC machine - is a register-only architecture, thus no mem-mem/mem-.reg ALU-operations like x86. Literals go to pools(!) which are normally placed near the consuming function(s), because of limited offset-range, etc. So: no, it is not "really similar". Other architectures like DSPs, smaller MCUs are often even more problematic. The `.rodata` section is a standard not only for ARM, but also for x86, etc for `const` variables.

Comment: @Olaf Yeah, I know it's a load/store architecture. [ARM makes a similar optimization](https://goo.gl/g85ame), [as does PowerPC](https://goo.gl/rIE7H0) and [even AVR does](https://goo.gl/Et7BSS)(tiny MCU). Having only load instructions for smaller regions doesn't mean you have to store that variable somewhere :L It just means you have to translate the number into parts so you can load the parts. Still makes no sense to have a pool of literals when you can inline them. GCC tends to lean toward my side of the fence on that one.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode: Well, gcc did **not** up to and including 4.63. for Cortex-M3 at least. It did use `ldr` and literal pools. Resulting in bad performance as thes MCUs have Flash which is much slower and data-loads could hardly be cached as instruction loads are on STM32F2+. Problem is once you have a variable, it will not use literals anymore, but access the pool. This includes the requirement to load the address into a register first, then load indiect. A literal load will be PC-relative with a (possibly) short instruction and no extra register spent (register trashing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `static const` variable will be a compile-time constant unless `volatile` or initialized by a function.
(with any decent optimizing compiler, anyway)

So if you do go with `static const` variables, you could get a speed increase *and* a smaller binary.

An example would be:

```
extern volatile const int n;

int main(){
    volatile int i = n;
}

volatile const int n = 5;
```

Which has the x86 assembly:

```
main:
    mov eax, DWORD PTR n[rip]
    mov DWORD PTR [rsp-4], eax
    xor eax, eax
    ret
n:
    .long   5
```

we have to use `volatile` to force the compiler to take the variable's address (that would happen if the variable weren't `volatile` but were in another translation unit) and not optimize out the `int i`.

That same example with `static const`:

```
static const int n = 5;

int main(){
    volatile int i = n;
}
```

has the x86 assembly:

```
main:
    mov DWORD PTR [rsp-4], 5
    xor eax, eax
    ret
```

We don't have to use `volatile` on the constant because we would be exposing the variable exactly the same way as if we were using a header, but we still need to stop the compiler optimizing out `i`.

You can see that the `static const` way has one less instruction and that the `extern` way has extra data added to the binary for the literal that needs to be stored for reference.

So we get better performance ***and*** a smaller binary. Although, I admit, these examples are pretty trivial.

This is actually still not a perfect representation, either. If we had `const int n` defined in another translation unit, without link-time optimizations, the compiler wouldn't be able to output `n: .long 5` and would have to reference another variable. But we'll give the example the benefit of the doubt.

These optimizations are extremely common and you can essentially rely on it being available.

The only thing to watch out for is if you write something like this:

```
static const int n = some_func();

int main(){
    volatile int i = n;
}
```

the compiler won't be able to substitute `n` for its literal value. This would add bloat to your binary because you're defining it in a header and it will be re-declared once in every translation unit. So `extern` would be better for space in that case, maybe not in speed though; you can test that yourself. Just mix and match if you really need to micro-optimize.

[all of the examples were compiled with gcc 4.9.2 from https://gcc.godbolt.org/ and used the flag -O3]

Answer (score 2):

Your suggestion is valid code, and it *might* increase your runtime speed and *might* increase the size of your executable.

In both cases it depends on how good your compiler is at optimizing.

Conceptually, the `static const` version means that each translation unit has its own copy of the constants.

But it also means that there is greater ability for optimization, since the compiler can see the values of the constants; it may include the value directly in whatever calculation is being used, as opposed to retrieving a value from a linked memory location.

Comment: Did you mean to say "might decrease the size"?

Comment: @TrevorHickey no. It might increase the size because it makes every unit have a copy of the constants, whereas originally there was only one copy for the whole program.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  In some examples it can be seen to decrease program size, but as you stated here, it has the potential to increase program size as well.

Comment: Yeah it all depends on the compiler really.

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think that hurts performance or executable size. (Instead, it might improve performance.)

There might be valid reasons to prefer `extern`.
E.g.: your `const long double` values are compiled into a shared library. For any programs using the library, these const variables can change accordingly when you change your compiled library. That is to say you only re-compile the shared library when you want to change their values. In contrast, if you use a single header in this case, you need to re-compile all programs to make them updated.

Comment: Yes, you never know when the value of π might need to be changed. :-)

Comment: @rici for example, precision

Comment: @rici another example, you may want to use a fake π when you are developing a game

Comment: @Griddoor: Huh? What is a fake π? And where is a shared library? OP only states it will be in two modules. I assume that is for a specific project.

Comment: @Olaf I mean like `3`, `3.1`, or any number fitting the game design. Sometimes the measurements in game are difference from the physics and mathematics in our world. Yes OP doesn't mention shared library or specific project. Only code base is mentioned. So I discussed what I can think of.

Comment: @Griddoor: The it would not be PI anymore. The ide to use `long double` is likely to have the max. precision available. So once you have the value at max. precision, it is complete nonsense to change that. If you are for speed, you have to use a smaller type (and likely use `#define`s, because only those are true _constants_), thus you have to change the declarations anyway.

Comment: @Olaf I never mentioned speed. Only design. Like games using hexagon/square grid. Imagine a world where π=4.

Comment: @Griddoor: squaring the circle? Nonsense. If you did, people would not be able to orientate anymore. It would become too uncommon.